# Could a person be the Dean of a University and the head of a company?

Tags: employment

per [Andrew W. Moore's self introduction](https://twitter.com/awmcmu?lang=en), he is the "Dean of the School of Computer Science at Carnegie Mellon University" and the "head of Google Cloud AI" at the same time. Is this legal?

Comment: It might be legal but also against a policy of the University or require permission of the school.

Comment: Hello baojieqh!  Welcome to Law.SE.  Please read the tour page linked at the bottom of this page.

Comment: Note that Carnegie Mellon University is a private college that can make its own rules regarding whether or not other employment is allowed more freely than a public university might be allowed to.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "legal", and the specifics of that relationship. Usually, there is a university policy prohibiting full-time faculty from holding other jobs (setting aside the summer-job exception for 9-month employees, which administrators are not). This would violate such a policy and possibly be grounds for termination – as violation of the terms of the contract. In the typical broad sense of "legal" used here, an act that violates a contract is not "legal". In the case of state universities, it might be a violation of a statute, which is even more clearly "illegal". However, faculty members are generally not prohibited from taking largely symbolic or minimum-work type jobs: the relevant consideration is whether the outside job interferes with their faculty position.
There's no reasonable way to determine the legal status of this particular appointment and side job.

Comment: "Usually, there is a university policy prohibiting full-time faculty from holding other jobs"  This is certainly not true at Cambridge University.  I know someone who was Professor of Civil Engineering and ran his own company.

Comment: Cambridge never falls in the realm of "usual".

Comment: I searched "professor of engineering company" and found the regulations for ETH (I'm in Zürich).  OK, it's a top tier university like Cambridge, but it allows full-time professors to have side jobs provided they take less than one day a week.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes

People are allowed to have more than one job.

Comment: I'm not.  It explicitly says so in my contract.